# How to override @WebInitParam of servlet without recompilation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have a Java Servlet with the following `@WebServlet` annotation:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/GetInfo"},
            initParams={
                @WebInitParam(name="directory.path", value="/appli/PdlInfo")})
```

How can I change the value of `@WebInitParam` without recompiling the servlet?

Comment: You'd to have a look at the init-param section of your web.xml

Comment: Besides editing web.xml, there is a possibility of implementing dynamic evaluation of @WebInitParameter during servlet initialization. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74122524/466677

Answer (score 4):

In Servlet 3.0 the annotations provide only the default value.
Using simply the web.xml file (or the tools available on the container at deployment time) you could change it. Either case you need to give the servlet a meaningful name:

```
    @WebServlet(
            name="GetInfo"
            urlPatterns={"/GetInfo"},
            initParams={@WebInitParam(name="directory.path",value="/appli/PdlInfo")}
    )
```

For web.xml here is a snippet:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetInfo</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>directory.path</param-name>
        <param-value>/other/path</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to override the "directory.path" variable without recompiling the class. Add a `web.xml` file to your `WEB-INF` folder, that defines a a new init parameter.

Change the `servlet-class` to the actual servlet class you are using.

A restart of the container is necessary in order to take the changes into consideration, but no recompiling / rebuilding is needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServletLinkName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>your.path.to.servlet.YourServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>directory.path</param-name>
            <param-value>/new/path</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServletLinkName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetInfo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use a dynamic parameter that changes while the application runs, you could use a properties file that it is watched by a thread and inspected in a interval of X seconds.

You may use a context param containing the location of the file together with a context initialized listener. The listener creates a watcher thread that updates some public variable that it is accessible by all your servlets.