# Is it possible to get the values dynamically in @WebInitParam?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a JSP page wherein user has to enter some custom URL. I want to pass that custom url in @WebInitParam in my servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "oauthCustomURL", initParams = {
     @WebInitParam(name = "clientId", value = "123"),
     @WebInitParam(name = "key", value = "***"),
     @WebInitParam(name = "environment", value = "customUrl"),
}) //in value I want to pass the value entered by user
```

Comment: you want to pass a value the user enters in your jsp to your servlet?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass it in @WebInitParam

Comment: that doesn't really make much sense though. WebInitParam isn't used for this kind of thing. So you want every user who makes a request to the servlet to have a clientId of 123?? You cannot change WebInitParam in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

@WebInitParam's are used for the configuration of servlets implemented by third-party libraries. Usually, these libraries use methods getInitParameterNames() and getInitParameter() of abstract class GenericServlet (but you should check in library code for it).

For the dynamic setting of the @WebInitParam you can override those methods in your servlet implementation. Below is an example of how to do it.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/abc/*")
public class DynamicInitParamServlet extends SomeCustomLibraryHttpServlet {
private static final String WEB_INIT_PARAM_NAME = "some.param.name";
private Integer webInitParamValue = null;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // calculate init param value dynamically,
    // TODO: implement your own code
    webInitParamValue = 2 * 3;

    // call custom library servlet init after init parameter value is set
    super.init(config);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
    if (webInitParamValue != null) {
        final Set<String> initParameterNames = new HashSet<>(Collections.list(super.getInitParameterNames()));
        initParameterNames.add(WEB_INIT_PARAM_NAME);
        return Collections.enumeration(initParameterNames);
    } else {
        return super.getInitParameterNames();
    }
}

@Override
public String getInitParameter(String name) {
    if (WEB_INIT_PARAM_NAME.compareTo(name) == 0 && webInitParamValue != null) {
        return "" + webInitParamValue;
    } else {
        return super.getInitParameter(name);
    }
}
}
```